# Loading and processing 1000s of files in R

Tags: python, r, multicore

I'm a bit new to R so please excuse the tinge of newbie here...

I am writing code in R to load 1000s of saved dataframes (files) in a script that runs a function on the data in each file and stores the resulting value in a vector. I have to do this over and over with different functions and it is taking a very long time at the moment.

I am attempting to parallelize the process using multicore mclapply but, unfortunately, anything from 2 - 8 cores seems to take even longer than simply running it on one core.

Is this idea fundamentally unsound due to disk I/O limitations? Is multicore, or even R, not the right solution? Would opening the files in something like Python and then running R functions on the contents be a better path than R?

Any guidance or thoughts on this would be appreciated -

Code added for clarity:

```
    library(multicore)

    project.path = "/pathtodata/"

    #This function reads the file location and name, then loads it and runs a simple statistic
    running_station_stats <- function(nsrdb_stations)
    {
      varname <- "column_name"
      load(file = paste(project.path, "data/",data_set_list[1], sep = ""))
      tempobj <- as.data.frame(coredata(get(data_set_list[2])))
      mean(tempobj[[varname]],na.rm=TRUE)
    }



    options(cores = 2)

    #This file has a list of R data files data_set_list[1] and the names they were created with data_set_list[2]
    load(file = paste(project.path, "data/data_set_list.RData", sep = ""))

    thelist <- list()

    thelist[[1]] <- data_set_list[1:50,]

    thelist[[2]] <- data_set_list[51:100,]

    thelist[[3]] <- data_set_list[101:150,]

    thelist[[4]] <- data_set_list[151:200,]


    #All three of these are about the same speed to run regardless of the num of cores
    system.time(
    {
      apply(nsrdb_stations[which(nsrdb_stations$org_stations==TRUE),][1:200,],1,running_station_stats)
    })

    system.time(
      lapply(thelist, apply, 1, running_station_stats)
     )

    system.time(
      mclapply(thelist, apply, 1, running_station_stats)
    )
```

Comment: There is no way to know unless you show us what your code is doing, and others can only guess. You can test yourself whether file access is the limiting issue or if it is something else. Once you pare down the problem to its components you'll start answering the question for yourself.

Comment: If the data are already in dataframes, then marshaling a R native format through another language will probably only slow things down. But as mdsumner noted, we can only guess based on what you've shown.

Comment: mdsumner - If there is something in this simplified code example that jumps out at you as a performance dog, let me know. If I discover something that speeds up the processing I'll post it here.

Answer (score 1):

Both Python and R will try to use multiple cores for things like your number crunching.  It doesn't help with reading large numbers of files. Multiple threads are also not the answer (re [python GIL](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)).

Some possible solutions (none of them simple) are:

- Use something like twisted where you can (some) of your file io async. Hard programming and it's not very numpy friendly.
- Use Celery or some other home grown master slave solution.  A lot of roll your own action.
- Use Ipython (w/ [ipcluster](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/parallel_process.html)) to spawn multiple processes that python will recombine for you (BEST solution IMO)

Comment: Thanks for the comment and suggestions. I'll post back if any of those pan out.

Comment: The GIL is a python threading problem. The multicore package in R does not suffer from this problem. However reading a lot of files is more limited by the amount of available disk io, not the amount of threads. I think the python `multiprocessing` library does not suffer from the GIL. This solution is similar to lpython.

Answer (score 0):

I would try good old-fashioned multiprocessing in Python first. The options above are all possible as well. Here's an example of doing a batch job with the multiprocessing module.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
```

def worker(x):
    time.sleep(0.2)
    print "x= %s, x squared = %s" % (x, x*x)
    return x*x

def apply_async():
    pool = mp.Pool()
    for i in range(100):
        pool.apply_async(worker, args = (i, ))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if **name** == '**main**':
    apply_async()

and the output looks like this:

```
x= 0, x squared = 0
x= 1, x squared = 1
x= 2, x squared = 4
x= 3, x squared = 9
x= 4, x squared = 16
x= 6, x squared = 36
x= 5, x squared = 25
x= 7, x squared = 49
x= 8, x squared = 64
x= 10, x squared = 100
x= 11, x squared = 121
x= 9, x squared = 81
x= 12, x squared = 144
```

As you can see, the numbers are not in order, as they are being executed asynchronously. Just change the worker() function above to do your processing, and possibly change the number of concurrent processes with the mp.Pool(10) or mp.Pool(15) or whatever. Something like that should be relatively strait forward. . .